# Why would trying to allocate a 2D array in C++ cause a memory corruption error?

Tags: c++, c++11, malloc

I have this code, trying to allocate a 2D array:

```
int** arr;
int rows = 32;

arr = new int*[rows];
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new int[64];
}
```

On line `arr = new int*[rows]`, I get the following error:

```
malloc(): memory corruption

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at                 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

Why would this be happening? I'm not accessing any memory outside of what's allocated, just allocating new memory right there.

Comment: The problem is probably elsewhere. Provide a [mcve] and we'ill be able to help you.

Comment: why does this have the cuda tag?

Comment: You will likely have to solve this one yourself. Remember that heap corruption can be caused much earlier in your program's execution. The crash need not happen right after you corrupted the heap. The code presented is most likely not the cause.

Comment: please explain with more details and complete code to view what happened